# What is the headpiece on Chi from Chobits called?

Tags: chobits

I can't for the life of me remember what it's called, and how many different purposes did it serve?

Comment: For those uninformed... which headpiece?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the "ears", they're literally called "ears". As for the function, there's different ports that are part of the ear assembly, and for most persocoms, that's where the on/off switch is (Chi's on/off switch is elsewhere). For persocoms that don't charge through solar power, the charging outlet is also part of the ear assembly.

[image]

Comment: *Chi's on/off switch is elsewhere*. xD